# What are the license terms for using Casablanca (C++ REST SDK)?

Tags: c++, rest, casablanca

What are the licensing terms for using Casablanca SDK in a project?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at their [github page](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk), you'll see that they have a [`license.txt`](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/blob/master/license.txt) file:

> C++ REST SDK
>
> The MIT License (MIT)
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>
> All rights reserved.
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of
>   this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in
>   the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to
>   use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of
>   the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so,
>   subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
>   copies or substantial portions of the Software.